# Python, Pandas - applying function to each particular item

Tags: python, pandas

Please help to newbie) 
I would like to draft a function, which could be applied to each particular item in Series. The thought is following: function looking on each particular item and compare it with items from another row and in another Series; if the condition of function is met, the condition returns as a new item into new Series; after that function going to the next item in applying Series.

Basing on my simple knowledge, I has the following function, but it doesnt work (kernel just busy w/o any result):

```
def trail_stop(high, low, close):
  for row in close:
    i = -1
    run = True  
    high.s = high.shift(i)
    low.s = low.shift(i)
    trail = (close + 0.0002)
    stop_loss = (close - 0.0002)
    while run == True:
      if high.s[0] > trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:
        stop_loss = trail
        trail = trail + 0.0002
        i = i - 1
      elif low.s[0] > stop_loss:
        return stop_loss
        run = False
      elif high.s[0] < trail and low.s[0] < stop_loss:
        i = i - 1
      else:
        run = False

table['trail'] = table.apply(trail_stop(table.High, table.Low, table.Close), axis = 1)
```

On the real input data (Close, High, Low) I want to receive the following Series as output(trail):

```
        High      Low    Close    trail
0    1.32396  1.32358  1.32391  1.32371
1    1.32392  1.32365  1.32365  1.32385 
2    1.32370  1.32364  1.32369  1.32389 
3    1.32378  1.32365  1.32371  1.32391 
4    1.32378  1.32360  1.32360  1.32380 
5    1.32390  1.32366  1.32370  1.32390 
6    1.32384  1.32370  1.32384  1.32364 
7    1.32386  1.32355  1.32380  1.32360 
8    1.32384  1.32358  1.32379  None
9    1.32389  1.32379  1.32387  None 
10   1.32386  1.32379  1.32383  1.32363 
11   1.32394  1.32360  1.32387  None 
12   1.32389  1.32370  1.32370  1.32390  
13   1.32390  1.32370  1.32390  1.32370 
14   1.32390  1.32364  1.32387  None  
15   1.32382  1.32373  1.32382  None
```

I will appreciate for any advise with this matter)

Upd.: additional example of input data:

```
   High     Low   Close
1.32396 1.32391 1.32394
1.32397 1.32391 1.32396
1.32396 1.32391 1.32396
1.32397 1.32394 1.32396
1.32398 1.32393 1.32393
1.32396 1.32392 1.32396
1.32396 1.32390 1.32396
1.32398 1.32390 1.32396
1.32398 1.32391 1.32396
1.32398 1.32385 1.32397
1.32397 1.32387 1.32395
1.32433 1.32398 1.32409
1.32417 1.32404 1.32417
1.32418 1.32406 1.32413
1.32436 1.32412 1.32436
1.32453 1.32429 1.32451
1.32454 1.32451 1.32453
1.32458 1.32447 1.32452
1.32454 1.32416 1.32424
1.32449 1.32419 1.32449
1.32451 1.32421 1.32438
```

Comment: Can you post examples of the input data?

Comment: Added to the post as update

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand what you want do, please comment your code or rewrite your text so that it's clearer.